# Prevent Default not working randomly when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Going through some old code and it appears the e.preventdefault() isn't behaving correctly on a button click. I am not sure how I didn't notice this before, but for some reason it just Simpy isn't doing its job. Page still refreshed even if If statement is executed. Am I missing something, am I blind? Can anyone tell what's going on here?

Also, I would like to add, it definetly gets into the IF statement, because the DIV that needs to be un-hidden does show, however page gets refreshed anyway and it submits which it should not.

Below is my code:

Thank you.

Form:

```
    <form class="form-group" method="get" action="#">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Terminal</th>
                        <th>Command</th>
                        <th>Command Value</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalsDDL, Model.TerminalsDDL, new { id = "ddlTerminalID", @class = "form-control align-middle" })</td>
                        <td onchange="UpdateHelpDescript();">@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalCommandLookupsDDL, Model.TerminalCommandLookupsDDL, new { id = "ddlCommandValue", @class = "form-control align-middle" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.UserEnteredTerminalCommands, new { Class = "form-control align-middle", Id = "cmdValueValue" })</td>
                        <td> <input id="btnSaveTerminalCommand" type="button" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary align-middle" /> </td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
   $(function () {
    $("#btnSaveTerminalCommand").click((e) => {

        if ($("#ddlCommandValue").val() == " " || $("#ddlCommandValue").val() == null || $("#ddlCommandValue").val() == 0 || $("#cmdValueValue").val() == " " || $("#cmdValueValue").val() == null) {

             //window.alert("Please select a valid command.");
             $("#alertPopUp").removeClass("hidden");
             e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        };

        var data = {
            TerminalID: $("#ddlTerminalID").val(),
            CommandID: $("#ddlCommandValue").val(),
            CommandValue: $("#cmdValueValue").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddTerminalCommand", "TerminalCommand")',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Success");
                window.location.href = response.Url;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only preventing default only when your conditional is true but you actually  want it prevented always since you are using ajax

```
 $("#btnSaveTerminalCommand").click((e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         if(....)
```

Within your conditional add a `return` to prevent the ajax executing with invalid data

Also note that `$(selector).val()` will return string and not `null`

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? That term is almost meaningless

Comment: Did you return true or just return?

Comment: Just saw your update! It works! Thank you so much. I've been stumped on this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be. The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event listeners calls stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation(), either of which terminates propagation at once.

In other words, it won't break out of your code. It will just prevent other handlers up the DOM that bubble out of this one to react to the event.

Perhaps you want to do a return statement after your call to  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Comment: Have you tried `return true;` at the end of your `if` block?

Comment: @Paurian would not return `true`... `false` or nothing